# Moving focus to external application (Chrome) and back to Emacs

Tags: frames, focus

I was wondering what is the most efficient way to move in and out of Emacs windows.

In my workflow I use Chrome and Emacs constantly, so I am curious as to how other users have managed to move amongst windows without using ALT-TAB.

Comment: Depends on the OS. With Mac you can do this with AppleScripts.

Comment: [wmctrl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl)?